# Why is "quotient" translated as 「商」 in mathematics?

Tags: meaning, glyph-origin

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient) defines "quotient" as:

> In arithmetic, a quotient (from Latin: quotiens "how many times", pronounced /ˈkwoʊʃənt/) is the quantity produced by the division of two numbers.[1]

Does the character 「商」 have the meaning of "how many times" from its origin?
Why is "quotient" translated as 「商」?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the etymology of “商” in “商数”](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/13846/4072)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<kbd>[商](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shang_dynasty)
[甲](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_bone_script)
[image]
[河](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)687
[合集24225](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=24225&jgwfl=)</kbd>

「商」 (*to measure* > *calculate, approximate, discuss* > (1) *quotient*, (2) *commerce*) was originally comprised of [「辛」 (*picture of a chisel or torture weapon*](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=706) > *hardship, difficulty*) and [「丙」 (*picture of a workshop table*)](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=157), indicating trade professions involving *measurement* (e.g. of raw materials and dimensions). This is one of the earliest and most literal meanings of the word 「商量」.

「口」 was later added as a *proper noun mark*, referring to the name of the [*Shang Dynasty*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shang_dynasty).

<kbd>商
[金](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_bronze_inscriptions)
[image]
商婦甗
[集成867](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=867&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>[戰國](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warring_States_period)・[楚](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chu_(state))
金
[image]
曾侯乙鐘
[集成290](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=290&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>[秦](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qin_dynasty)
[簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bamboo_and_wooden_slips)
[image]
[日甲](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/QinwenziReference)145
[睡虎地秦簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuihudi_Qin_bamboo_texts)</kbd><kbd>今
[楷](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_script)
[image]</kbd>

> Compare the similar addition of 「口」 (or its derivatives [「甘」](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=264) and [「曰」](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=137)) in the characters [「周」](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=802) ([*Zhou Dynasty*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zhou_dynasty)), [「曹」](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=2172) ([*State of Cao*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cao_(state))), [「曾」](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=2606) ([*State of Zeng*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sui_(state))), etc.

*To measure* was later extended to mean *approximation* or *calculation*, and then specialised to mean *quotient*, derived from its use as a kind of jargon in [rod calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rod_calculus).

> See a [rod calculus tutorial on computing the square root of 234567](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rod_calculus#Extraction_of_Square_root). The top row in this calculation layout is called 「商」.

---

**References:**

- 季旭昇《說文新證》
- [小學堂](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/)
- [國學大師](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/)

  - [郭沫若《甲骨文合集》](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/)
  - [中國社會科學院考古研究所《殷周金文集成》](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/)

Comment: "Measure" is actually a more apropos reference than one might think - and the relevant cognition appears in other cultures as well: e.g. if one looks to the classic Greek text by Euclid, the *Elements*, division of one number by another is called "measuring" the one by the other. A quotient, $a/b$, can be interpreted as "given a quantity $a$, measure it out in units of size $b$, and give its value in terms of those units". And this is also how all physical measurements work, too - in effect, you're taking the "quotient" of one physical object by another, reference

Comment: object (the unit), to yield a number.

Comment: Hence 商量, "measured quantity", is pretty much perfect: "the measured quantity [商量] formed by measuring a in units of b", is a/b.